# NSString -initWithContentOfFile error - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I'm trying to load to an `NSString`, the content of my file named `names.txt`, in the directory of the project. To do this, I have the following code :

```
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *names = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"names" ofType:@"txt"] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
    if (error != nil) {
        [NSException raise:@"Error reading file :" format:@"%@",error];
    }
```

And I'm getting `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Error reading file :', reason: 'Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=258 "The file name is invalid."'`. I couldn't find any other cases like that. What's wrong with this code?

Comment: `pathForResource:ofType:` can't find the file and is returning `nil`.

Comment: Are you sure the extension is `txt`? Have you right-clicked the file in `Finder`, clicked "Get Info" and checked the extension there under "Name & Extension"?

Comment: I'm sure, the file's name is `names` and its extension is `txt`

Comment: Is that on a mac or on ios? Have you tried `pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:` already?

Comment: I'm working on Mac and no, haven't tried that.

Comment: Try logging `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"names" ofType:@"txt"]`

Comment: Did it already, got `(null)`. It can't get the path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure that your names.txt file is included under the Copy Bundle Resources region of the Xcode Build Phases window for your target.

In the debugger, you could test for a valid bundle file with:

```
  ...
  NSString *file  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"names" ofType:@"txt"];
  /* FILE ought not be nil. NSAssert (file) */
  NSString *names = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: file
                                                    encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                       error: &error];
```

Comment: When I log `file`, I get `(null)` and the file is in the Xcode project, under the main folder...

Comment: That means the file is not part of the application's bundle.  The file needs to be listed under 'Copy Bundle Resources'; check there.  It is likely that if you put names.txt into the 'Supporting Files' group then it will be automatically added to 'Copy Bundle Resources'

Comment: Okay, now make sure it is listed under 'Copy Bundle Resources'.  (Select your 'Project'; then select your 'Target'; then select 'Build Phases'; then open 'Copy Bundle Resources' and check for names.txt.)

Comment: There are no such thing as 'Copy Bundle Resources', there is 'Copy Files', added the file there, nothing changed.

Comment: Then make sure it is copied.  Play around with the `destination` (try 'Resources' first but others if that one doesn't work).

Comment: I don't get how to be sure if it copied.

Comment: Drag it from the 'left hand side file listing' into the 'Copy Files' window; make the Destination to be 'Resources'.  Build and Run.  It works for me.  Good luck.

Comment: Even doing that, nothing changes, I'll put a screenshot to make sure I made the correct things.

Comment: Sorry I can't it seems that I must have at least 10 rep

Comment: To resume, under the Navigator, `names.txt` is under `Supporting Files`. `Under Target -> Build Phases -> Copy Files`, `Destination = Resources`, `Subpath = nothing`, `copy only when installing` is checked, and `names.txt` is there.

Comment: Uncheck 'copy only when installing'.  Note: you've got 10 rep now. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (error != nil) {
```

No no no no no. That is not the correct test. The test is

```
if (nil == names) {
```

The value of `error` tells you *nothing* about whether we succeeded. It is the nil value returned that tells you if there was a problem. Then, and only then, you may read the error.

Comment: I know. But I couldn't stand to see you doing this wrong, and it *can* get you in serious trouble.

Comment: So, just for understanding this, is it possible that the error isn't nil and the string has been generated with success?

Comment: It can happen. There are no guarantees about the value of the error unless the string is nil!